# find ascii number in a string

Tags: php, ascii

I have a string of random digits. And I want to input a number (or char) and find it's position in a string.

it works fine if I use code like this:

```
<?php
$string='14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196';
$string_to_convert=$_POST["number_to_convert"];
$number_to_find=ord($string_to_convert);
if(strpos($string,$string_to_convert)===false){
    echo "not found";
}
else{
echo strpos($string,$string_to_convert)+1;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="textarea" name="number_to_convert"></input>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

But when I try to use code like this:

```
<?php
$string='14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196';
$string_to_convert=$_POST["number_to_convert"];
$number_to_find=ord($string_to_convert);
if(strpos($string,$number_to_find)===false){
    echo "not found";
}
else{
echo strpos($string,$number_to_find)+1;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="textarea" name="number_to_convert"></input>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

It shows not found if THERE IS this number, and some random number if THERE ISNT number like this.

So what can be wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine http://runnable.com/me/VFpaIkcwbzADRrhK

Comment: "Sorry, but the page you are trying to view does not exist." :)

Comment: try this http://runnable.com/VFpbQVz5pPoCf8ww/pi-for-php

Comment: so as I guessed from the example you've provided, my $number_to_find has to be a string, not an int, right?

Comment: yes, there was the point, I had to convert it to string. anyway, thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially you need to check , whether the posted data of the variable is set and write the logic, so you will came to know , the data you are fetching correctly or not. thank you

```
if(isset($_POST['number_to_convert'])){
   // your logic goes here . . . . . 
  }
```

Try this if you are still facing problem, let me know , don't need to hesitate.